# Return distinct rows based on matching data in a column in another table in PosgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table (e_v2) with some time-series data. I want to fetch all rows where the data in the "POINT_KEY" column appears in the "KEY" column in another table (etraining_v1). The code below (I'm unsure whether it's correct) did return some rows, but there are many duplicates. I would like to exclude the duplicates.

```
SELECT * FROM e_v2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM etraining_v1 WHERE "POINT_KEY" = etraining_v1.key)
ORDER BY 
"POINT_KEY",
"INTERVAL_READING"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row of e_v2 will be returned at most once by your query.  Any duplicate values you are getting are duplicates that already exist in e_v2.  You can remove them by adding a "DISTINCT" before your select-list.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM e_v2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM etraining_v1 WHERE "POINT_KEY" = etraining_v1.key)
ORDER BY 
"POINT_KEY",
"INTERVAL_READING"
```

Or you an clean up e_v2 so that it doesn't contain duplicates.

Comment: Does the 1 after SELECT that you added instructs the query to only select 1 row where "POINT_KEY" matches etraining_v1.key? If so, is the distinct still necessary ? Thanks

Comment: No, it makes no difference to that. I added it just because I think it is clearer and more portable to write it that way.  An empty select-list is a peculiarity.